# Faire un tabac, is its origin tabasser?

Tags: verbes, phrase

I believe "faire un tabac" means a resounding success but I heard it comes from the verb "tabasser" which means to beat or pound, make noise. Where is the connection with tobacco or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Faire un tabac*** and *[**tabasser**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tabasser)* share the same origin, along with other expressions mentioning *tabac* like ***coup de tabac*** and ***passer à tabac***.

None of them are related to tobacco though. The spelling ***tabac*** has been used possibly because it was convenient and was pronounced the same and probably by joke, as says the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tabac/1).

In all of these expressions, *tabac* comes from the root ***tabb-*** (cognates with ***tapp-*** that gave ***taper***) found in the occitan ***tabastar*** which also gave *[**tarabuster**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tarabuster)*.

[image]

Frédéric Mistral, *Lou tresor dóu Felibrige*, 1878

Comment: thank you,yes. That sometimes happens in English to, I know, as in'' to toe the line'' is often mistaken as ''to tow the line'' and ''champing at the bit ''is wrongly said incorrectly as ''chomping at the bit''. There may be more

Comment: @Bluelion7 Reminds me of a competent linguistics prof who was to my surprise unsure whether the original was "home in on" or "hone in on". (It's the first.) Anyway, these are called [eggcorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn).

Comment: @LukeSawczak cool! I never heard the word "eggcorn" before

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes. The initial ((etymo)logical) spelling was *faire un tabas* but the expression was quickly written  *faire un tabac* and the ephemerous *tabas* was lost.